# jcraft jsch SSH with udpated linux

Tags: linux, ssh, jsch

We recently updated some older systems from Ubuntu 14 LTS to Ubtuntu 16 LTS.  When we did so, some of our older ssh clients are not able to connect to the newer Ubuntu 16, including our automated tools that use jcraft.jsch, the java SSH library.

JSCH claims to implement SSH2, and that is what our new server uses, so I think it should work.  Are there any flags I need to set to get have JSCH to connect with newer ubuntu/linux versions programmatically from within a Java app.

Comment: This question focuses on a java library that is used for ssh. It should not be put on hold, in my opinion.

Comment: I agree that your question is not off topic, but I think it is too broad and too abstract as it stands; you are asking for a solution without having detailed the problem to be solved. Can you modify it to focus on the specific issue(s) that arose when _"older ssh clients are not able to connect to the newer Ubuntu 16"_?

Comment: I particularly did not vote for the question to be closed as *off-topic*, but as *too broad*, in accordance with what @skomisa wrote above.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, OpenSSH has deprecated a lot of older algorithms because they're insecure or weak, such as those using CBC, RC4 (arc4four), Diffie-Hellman group 1, and RIPEMD-160. While these algorithms still exist in the version of OpenSSH you're using, they have been or will be removed in future versions, and are disabled by default in Ubuntu 16.04.

You haven't specified the version of JSCH or other clients you're using, so it's not possible to determine for certain if this is the cause. It's also possible that if all of your clients are using Java, they're using Java before version 8, which only supports 1024-bit Diffie-Hellman, which is known to be insecure.

It's possible to enable the older algorithms by specifying the `Ciphers`, `KexAlgorithms`, and `MACs` options in the sshd configuration file. You can see the allowed and default values by running `man sshd_config` or using `ssh -Q` with an appropriate argument.

Modern versions of OpenSSH won't support 1024-bit Diffie-Hellman, so if that's your problem, you'll need to upgrade Java.

However, it's probably better to update your clients to use more modern versions. As mentioned above, these algorithms are going away, and functional and secure alternatives have been available for a while. The versions of JSCH and Java available in Ubuntu 16.04 should have support for the proper algorithms, although you may need to configure them appropriately, since they may not be enabled by default.

If you're interested, Mozilla provides a good description of a [secure configuration](https://infosec.mozilla.org/guidelines/openssh.html) you can use on your systems. The algorithm names are standardized, so you can use them in the configuration for any SSH client or server that supports them.

Comment: we are using JSCH 0.1.55  (JSCH-0.1.55.jar), which I think is the latest version.  Are you aware a setting that will allow us to connect to modern ubuntu with that version of JSCH?

Comment: I'm not sure how one configures JSCH. Theoretically that version should interoperate with OpenSSH, but you may want to look at the documentation and the Mozilla recommendations and configure it accordingly.

Comment: As @bk2204 said, adding `KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` helped my case.